Determinant of a projection map composed with another linear map
I am reading MasCollel book "The theory of General Economic Equilibrium" and it contains a short review of key mathematical concepts used further in the theory. He states the following claim without proof and suggests this result can be easily found in introductory texts of Linear Algebra. I studied upper-division linear algebra using "Linear Algebra done right". It was some time ago, and I have no memory of this result or something similar.
Suppose $A$ and $B$ are, respectively, $n \times n$ and $n \times m$ matrices with rank $B = m$. Let $L$ be the orthogonal complement to Range $B$, that is $L =$ Kernel $B^T$. Define a linear map $f : L \rightarrow L$ by $f(x) = \pi_L Ax$, where $\pi_L$ is the orthogonal projection on $L$. Then its determinant is equal to the determinant of the following bordered matrix
$$  M = \begin{matrix}
A & B \ \ \ \\
-B^T & 0 \ \ \ \\
\end{matrix} $$
multiplied by $\frac{1}{d}$, where $d$ is the sum of the squares of all the minors of $B$ corresponding to $m \times m$ submatrices.
My knowledge includes several facts that I am trying to combine to prove this result:

Given a n-dim vector space X with a basis V, for a fixed subspace $L$ the orthogonal projection map is given by the following matrix
$$ Mtx_{V}(\pi_L) = A(A^TA)^{-1}A^T $$
where $A = \{v_1,...,v_k\}$ is the basis for $L$.
Alternatively,
$$ \pi_L(x) = \sum_{i = 1}^k \frac{<v_i,x>}{<v_i,v_i>}v_i $$
but I vaguely remember this is only true for orthogonal basis.
I have no memories of working with bordered matrices, and the only fact I found that seems useful is that $det(M) = det(A) \cdot det(B^TA^{-1}B) $

I think what the first issue I am having is I cannot think of a way to express basis of Kernel$B^T$ using matrix $B$. Second issue is that $\pi_LA$ is a linear transformation from $L$ into $L$, but I cannot express the determinant of this composition matrix as a product of determinants, since $Mtx_V(\pi_L)$ is not a square matrix.

Since $\ker B^T=(\operatorname{range} B)^\perp$, $\pi_L$ is a matrix that maps any vector $v \in \operatorname{range} B$ to zero. If $\pi_L = I_n - B(B^TB)^{-1}B^T$ then $\pi_L Bx=0$ for all $x$.

This is very useful @TedBlack, thanks. If $\pi$ projects on a subspace $S$, then $I - \pi$ projects on $S^{\perp}$.

By Cauchy-Binet formula, your $d$ is simply equal to $\det(B^TB)$. By changes of orthonormal bases, you may assume that $A=\pmatrix{X&Y\\ Z&W}$ and $B=\pmatrix{0\\ C}$, where $C$ is an invertible $m\times m$ matrix and $W$ has the same size as $C$. Then $d=\det(B^TB)=\det(C)^2$ and the author is essentially claiming that
$$
\det(X)=\frac{1}{\det(B^TB)}\det\pmatrix{A&B\\ -B^T&0}
=\frac{1}{\det(C)^2}\det\pmatrix{X&Y&0\\ Z&W&C\\ 0&-C^T&0}.
$$
This holds because
\begin{align*}
&\det\pmatrix{X&Y&0\\ Z&W&C\\ 0&-C^T&0}\\
&=\det\left(\pmatrix{I_{n-m}&0&Y(C^T)^{-1}\\ 0&I_m&0\\ 0&0&I_m}
\pmatrix{X&Y&0\\ Z&W&C\\ 0&-C^T&0}
\pmatrix{I_{n-m}&0&0\\ 0&I_m&0\\ -C^{-1}Z&-C^{-1}W&I_m}\right)\\
&=\det\left(\pmatrix{I_{n-m}&0&Y(C^T)^{-1}\\ 0&I_m&0\\ 0&0&I_m}
\pmatrix{X&Y&0\\ 0&0&C\\ 0&-C^T&0}\right)\\
&=\det\pmatrix{X&0&0\\ 0&0&C\\ 0&-C^T&0}\\
&=\det(X)\det(C)^2.
\end{align*}

I cannot see how this derivation incorporates the projection matrix. I am sure it’s there , it’s just not obvious.

@user1551, this is great, thank you so much! I do have a clarification question though, that I feel relates to a couple of facts I have recently learned.
Fact 1: when one need to check definiteness of a real symmetric matrix A, $m \times m$ on a kernel of B $l \times m$, one can equivalently check that the last $(m-l)$ leading principal minors of the bordered Hessian alternate in sign and the determinant of this Hessian should satisfy $(-1)^{m+l}det (H) >0$
Fact 2: $x^T Ax > 0$ for all $x \in L$ is equivalent to to all eigenvalues of the map $\pi_LA$ being positive. Cont. next comment

@user1551, I do not follow how I can assume that A = a block matrix where upper block is $\pi_L A$.
Bordered Hessian from the previous comment is \begin{matrix} 0 & B \ B^T & A \end{matrix}
